# SQL AVG and SUM GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, subquery, sum, average

i have two tables, say **Costs** and **Payments**, and i need to calculate the AVG of monthly payments for each costs.

i.e. Costs_IdCost = 2 has three payments

```
+-----------+--------------+----------+--------+
| IdPayment | Costs_IdCost |   Date   | Amount |
+-----------+--------------+----------+--------+
|     1     |      2       |2012/09/10|  1000  |
+-----------+--------------+----------+--------+
|     2     |      2       |2012/09/20|  3000  |
+-----------+--------------+----------+--------+
|     3     |      2       |2012/10/01|  5000  |
+-----------+--------------+----------+--------+
```

now i need not just the average of payments (3000) but the average between:

```
September : (1000+3000)/2 = 2000
October   : 5000 /1 = 5000
AVG       : (2000+5000)/2 = 3500
```

and i'm getting pretty messy with group by and subquery >_<

thank you!

**--------------------EDIT---------------------------**

i'm using mySql, this is what i did so far:

```
SELECT c.IdCost,
c.Name,
c.Amount,
AVG(p.monthly_sum) Mean,
SUM( p.Amount ) Total,
COUNT( p.IdPayment ) Num
FROM Costs c
LEFT JOIN (SELECT MONTH(Date), 
        YEAR(Date), 
                    Costs_IdCost,
                    IdPayment,
                    Amount,
        AVG (Amount) monthly_sum
    FROM Payments
    GROUP BY YEAR(Date), MONTH(Date) 
     ) p ON p.Costs_IdCost = c.IdCost
GROUP BY c.IdCost
```

Comment: Show us what you have so far.

Comment: TSQL, MySQL, Oracle,...?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for but it will give you the desired results:

```
select date_format(date, '%Y-%m') Month,
  avg(amount) AvgAmount
from costs c
left join payments p
  on c.id = p.costs_idcost
group by date_format(date, '%Y-%m')
union all
select concat(cast(count(*) as char), ' Months Averaged'),
  avg(AvgAmount) TotalAvg
from
(
  select avg(amount) AvgAmount, 
    date_format(date, '%Y-%m') Month
  from costs c
  left join payments p
    on c.id = p.costs_idcost
  group by date_format(date, '%Y-%m')
) x
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dcc02/39)

Answer (score 1):

You can group by month part of date.

```
GROUP BY datepart(MONTH, Cost.Date)
```

This may not the most efficient way, but it might work nicely. BTW datepart is build in function of MSSQL.

Answer (score 0):

I do similar by using a select entry of

```
SELECT format(DATE_TIME,''yyyy-MM'') as [Month], .......

GROUP BY format(DATE_TIME,''yyyy-MM''), .........
```

The SORT BY is the same as what GROUP BY I am using.  Not that one can even got to the hour, minute and second level with this concept if you want 
example:  `SELECT format(DATE_TIME,''yyyy-MM-dd.HH'') as [Hour]`